# How can I position material on object better

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

My original image has 8 planks which I am 'wrapping' onto a large surface (9 metres X 3 metres) and I apply a scale of 5.6 in uv editing which results in 45 'planks' with about half (width) of one plank on one end and another half on the other end. Is it possible to end up with only full width planks.

Refer to the following images the first of the material and the second showing the object showing a half width 'plank on either end (marked with red arrows).

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can move (scale and rotate) faces on the UV plane using the UVMap editor on the left. I also suggest unwrapping the UVs only after you applied the scales.

Comment: Thanks Filip. Yes I am familiar with moving faces on the uv plane using the UVMap editor. Although I don't know about applying the scales before unwrapping the UVs. I only know about changing the Scale after unwrapping pressing the S key and then dragging the LMB or entering a value. I can't find anything on applying scale before unwrapping. Do you mean using texture coordinate and mapping nodes? That is an area I haven't yet tried to learn (I just found a Youtube tutorial named "How to Change Material Size in Blender the EASY WAY!" - don't know how I missed finding that before I posted this.

Comment: I did some tests and I think I'm wrong scaling and applying scale doesn't affect UV map. The problem is somewhere else. Can you show a screenshot of nodes of your material?

Comment: Thanks Philip. I think I am ok now. I selected the full width of the material which depicts 9 separate 'planks' and as I wanted 45 'planks' showing on my model I applied 5 as the scale 'factor' which divides equally into 45 as 9. Also I have learned that a scale factor up to 3 decimals places can be used which also helps.